# Unable to upgrade 3 packages after upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates

So I have upgraded my Ubuntu from 20.4 to 22.04. Now these three packages won't get upgraded -

```
python3-distupgrade ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
```

I have tried -

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

I am getting the message that these three packages have not been upgraded and instead kept back.

So how can I upgrade my packages?

Comment: It seems there are many reasons why the upgrade of some packages is blocked.
I did not upgrade to 22.04 from an earlier version and got the warning that 10 packages were upgradable but they would'nt upgrade.
In my case, changing the Ubuntu server and updating solved the problem.

Comment: @user535733 yes it answers my question, thank you